# B2B users cannot sign in to Tenant using v2.0 endpoint & MSAL Auth flow

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to create a B2B Management portal. I've started off with [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-sample) sample since it uses MSAL and Graph API.

*user@live.se* is in the tenant. It's been invited as a "guest user", i.e a B2B user. However, signing in with *user@live.se* does not work even though it's been added to the tenant. Following error after sign-in:

*AADSTS50020: User account 'user@live.se' from external identity provider 'live.com' is not supported for api version '2.0'. Microsoft account pass-thru users and guests are not supported by the tenant-independent endpoint. Trace ID: 2ad8bee0-d00a-4896-9907-b5271a113300 Correlation ID: 0ea84617-4aa1-4830-859f-6f418252765e Timestamp: 2017-10-03 15:35:22Z*

I changed the authority (from common) to only allow users from my tenant (requirement):
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0

Do guests not count as part of my tenant when using MSAL? that would mean I have to use "old" tech, i.e ADAL and AAD Graph, which is not recommended, and feels kinda lame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass the specific tenant value in the authority, then

> Only users with a **work or school account** from a specific Azure AD tenant can sign in to the application. Either the friendly domain name of the Azure AD tenant or the tenant's GUID identifier can be used.

That's means the **Microsoft Account** is not supported in this scenario. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/sign-up-organization) for the Microsoft Account and Work or school accounts. And in this scenario, if you new a user user from other tenant, it should also works.

You can refer the document for tenant from link below:

[Fetch the OpenID Connect metadata document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oidc)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread but just in case anyone stumbles upon it, here is a solution:
In cases of Personal guest accounts, use Credential Grant Flow ([Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)).
To do that, you would first need to grant appropriate permission (of Type **Application**) for the API you wanted to use on behalf of the signing user. This would let you acquire access token with the application's identity itself rather than the signed in user. 
Next get token like this (in this sample, I'm getting access token for Graph API):

```cs
public async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        string token = "";
        try
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> body = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"),
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", appSecret),
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials")
            };
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri($"{httpClient.BaseAddress}/oauth2/v2.0/token");
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body);
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>();
            token = content.access_token;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

**Tip**: If your goal is also Graph API, don't try to get logged in user info by using the ***/me*** endpoint in this case. Since the token was generated using the application identity rather than the signed in user, ***/me*** would be the application not the logged in user. What you want to do is: retrieve logged in user id from the Claim (Type: *http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier*) and use the ***/user/{userid}*** endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I found: for personal accounts (Get access without a user) in the body of the request you must to use `grant_type = 'client_credentials'` and for corporate accounts to use `grant_type = 'authorization_code'`