# Testing application with Azure Work accounts

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I am trying to test multi tenant Azure authentication to an application, which only works with Azure Work accounts ([B2B users cannot sign in to Tenant using v2.0 endpoint & MSAL Auth flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553313/b2b-users-cannot-sign-in-to-tenant-using-v2-0-endpoint-msal-auth-flow)).

Without asking our Azure AD admin to consent my testing application, what other options I have to use Work accounts ?

How hard is to create custom organization where I could test it ?

thank you

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer? If it is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only when the tenant administrator agrees to your multi-tenant application to access its tenant, you can use that tenant's users to test your application.

This is how multi-tenant applications work and this is the process that meets security.

You can create an [Azure free account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/) for testing purpose.

Comment: Thanks Allen. I have discovered that my organization has implemented an Azure client automated approval process. We have a wizard where it is possible to ask for new application Id - that is how I am testing my work account now. I was also wondering if it is possible to create a Work account on a free Azure subscription. Do you know what is the process ?

I thought I would need to create a custom domain to create work account. Is that the right way ?

Comment: @MartinKunc You can follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory#add-a-new-user to create the work account. There is no need to create a custom domain.